# Always round a decimal number upwards

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I can use the `ROUND` function to round to the nearest decimal.

```
5.1 = 5
5.5 = 6
```

What if I want like this:

```
5.1 = 6
5.5 = 6
```

What function should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ROUNDUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093443?hl=en) is exactly what you need here.

> Rounds a number to a certain number of decimal places, always rounding up to the next valid increment.

Comment: Thanks it works for me. I will accept answer in 10minutes.